# Server Configuration missing from right-click menu of Websphere server on RAD

Tags: eclipse, websphere, rad

I am working with RAD (9.6.1.3) and WebSphere8.5. I noticed that on the Servers tab, if I right-click on the server I no longer see the 'Server Configurations' menu item. See attached image. I am puzzled as to what caused this to happen and how to make that component visible again?
[screencap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9exfD.png)

I tried creating a new server profile as well as new workspace, with no luck.

Comment: Do you get the same result from the Properties or Open actions?

Comment: Yes, same result.